# Change minimumDate of angular UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

My problem is as follows; I have set a datepicker like this:

```
<div  ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input  name='gebdat' type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="someModell" is-open="opened" min="{{minimumDate}}" max="'2014-04-01'"  datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

It is mostly copied from here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Now I want to change the minimum Date of the Datepicker to the date 80 yrs before.
The js part looks like this:

```
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $filter) {


  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear()-80;

  if(today.getDate()==29&&today.getMonth()==1){
    var minDate = new Date(year,2,1); 
    }else{
        var minDate = new Date(year,today.getMonth(),today.getDate());
    }

  var minDate2=String(''+minDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(minDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+minDate.getDate()+'');
  $scope.minimumDate = minDate2;
 alert($scope.minimumDate); //and so on
```

The alert shows the date I wanted, but the datepicker doesn't seem to like it. Am I missing
something?
If I enter the minDate manually into the datepicker the right expression is: `min="'1934-02-12'"`

Edit:
It works if I just set $scope.minimumDate='1934-03-13'; so the problem must be somewhere at (at least i guess so):

```
var minDate2=String(''+minDate.getFullYear()+'-'+(minDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+minDate.getDate()+'');
      $scope.minimumDate = minDate2;
```

Comment: Can it be __$scope.minDate__ instead of __$scope.minimumDate__ ?

Comment: just tried it, doesn't work ... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with putting the controller part like this:

```
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $filter) {

  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear()-80;

  var minDate = new Date(year,today.getMonth(),today.getDate());

  var month = today.getMonth()+1;
  month='0'+month;
  var day = today.getDate();

  $scope.minimumDate = "'"+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"'";}
```